# Best constant for a trace inequality

Tags: sobolev-spaces, traces

> Having an open, simply connected set $\Omega \subset \Bbb{R}^N$ we may ask what is the best constant $C$ (if it exists) in the inequality
>   $$ \int_{\partial \Omega} u^2 \leq C\int_{\Omega} |\nabla u|^2$$
>   for functions $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ such that $\int_{\partial \Omega} u =0$.

The best constant is related to the first Steklov eigenvalue corresponding to $\Omega$. 
Do you know any references for results of this type? I am interested in the case of unbounded domains. For me $\Omega$ has fixed measure and bounded perimeter, but if any other necessary assumptions are needed, I'm still interested.

Comment: The integral at the LHS is on $\partial \Omega$, not on $\Omega$, right?

Answer (score 1):

Given a concrete bounded domain, the best constant can be evaluated by using FEM to solve the Stokes eigenvalue problem along with mathematically correct precision.

I am not sure whether this information is useful to you.

This is a new result in press (to appear soon). If you are interested, please contact me.